# Delete fetch api having some issues

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

```js
export const deleteZones = (id) => {
  console.log("abc"+id);
  return dispatch => {
      fetch(
          BASE_URL+"api/v1/beacon-groups/"+id,
          {
              method: 'Delete',
              headers: {
                  
                  'Authorization': localStorage.litiferJwt
              }
          }
      )
          .then(response => {
              if(response.status >= 400){
                  // TODO - proper error should be passed
                  throw new Error("error");
              }
              console.log("Deleted");
              store.dispatch(push('/tags'));
              return dispatch(zonesDeleted(response.json()));
          })
          
          .catch(err => {
              return dispatch(deleteFailed(err.message));
          })
  }
};
```

Here is my snippet I had provided.
What I'm doing now is, I'm deleting a particular record and want to hit the API.
Now I was able to hit the API and the record was deleted as well but the response which was expected I'm not getting that.
Even I had console in the response but its not printing in the console

Comment: did not worked at all

Comment: actually record getting deleted but not getting the response in console also

Comment: Put a console.log() in .then and .catch , put the console.log before `if(response.status >= 400){`

Comment: still nothing happenned

Comment: Are there no erros in console also , just try to remove spaces before, .then and .catch

Comment: after adding console.log in catch there's a warning of unreachable code

Comment: i had tried your code and added the screenshot

Comment: Piyush there is error in your API, check zones.action.js file. Can you post that part

Comment: it's a [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue try to add this to your headers `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"`

Comment: cors issue solution worked!!
haha no option to vote our answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919566/how-to-add-canvas-in-react-and-also-how-to-draw-rectangle-on-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue try to add this to your headers :

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919566/how-to-add-canvas-in-react-and-also-how-to-draw-rectangle-on-image